# Is it possible to make a harddrive a bootable device from a DVD

Tags: boot, iso-image

I do not have a big enough USB drive and my laptop doesnt have a dvd drive for the DVD I wish to boot.

I have been told I must create a bootable USB drive which I assume is done with the ISO image of the original DVD.

Can I use a Harddrive instead of a USB?

If not, why?

Comment: On Which operating system are you? And which one would you like to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can by creating a partition on your drive or if it is not your primary drive, you can create it on the drive without partitioning it first. You can look at [this](http://bootableusb.net/make-bootable-external-hdd-install-windows-78/) link I found after a quick google search.